# Draw rectangle around active window (C or Python)

Tags: python, add-on

I would like to try coding a simple Blender modification: to have the active window (i.e. The one beneath the mouse cursor) outline in orange, with the title bar also lighting in Orange.

Is it possible to do this from the Python level, or is it necessary to go down to the C level?

Answer (score 2):

It should be done in the C code, there's already something to highlight the active area.

With Python, you're pretty limited to draw handlers, which are attached to regions:

```
import bpy
import bgl

def draw_callback_px(self, context):

    # 50% alpha, 2 pixel width line
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5)
    lw = 4 // 2
    bgl.glLineWidth(lw*2)

    r = context.region

    bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_LINE_STRIP)
    bgl.glVertex2i(lw, lw)
    bgl.glVertex2i(r.width - lw, lw)
    bgl.glVertex2i(r.width - lw, r.height - lw)
    bgl.glVertex2i(lw, r.height - lw)
    bgl.glVertex2i(lw, lw)
    bgl.glEnd()

    # restore opengl defaults
    bgl.glLineWidth(1)
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)


class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Draw a line with the mouse"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal View3D Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            # the arguments we pass the the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
            bpy.ops.view3d.modal_operator({'area': area}, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')
            break
```